# change divs css values with jQuery in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hy!
I'm writing script which is about growing plants. My problem is with the jquery,css part. I have this loop:

```
var i,elementWaterLevel, elementLifeLevel, elementFloweringLevel,floweringTime;

    for (i = 0; i < globalNumberOfPlants; i++)
    {
        elementWaterLevel = $("#waterLevel[plantId=" + globalData[i].plantId + "]");
        elementLifeLevel = $("#lifeLevel[plantId=" + globalData[i].plantId + "]");
        elementFloweringLevel = $("#floweringLevel[plantId=" + globalData[i].plantId + "]");

        floweringTime = Math.round((globalData[i].currentFloweringTime / globalData[i].marijuanaFloweringTime) * 200);
        elementWaterLevel.css("height", Math.round((globalData[i].currentWaterLevel) * 220));
        elementLifeLevel.css("height", Math.round((globalData[i].currentLifeLevel) * 220));
        elementFloweringLevel.css("width", floweringTime);

        if (globalData[i].currentLifeLevel == 0) {
            $("#littlePlantStatus[plantId=" + globalData[i].plantId + "]").css("border", "5px solid red");
        }
        else {
            if (globalData[i].currentFloweringTime / globalData[i].plantFloweringTime == 1) {
                $("#littlePlantStatus[plantId=" + globalData[i].plantId + "]").css("border", "5px solid green");
                $("#harvestThePlant[plantId=" + globalData[i].plantId + "]").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#littlePlantStatus[plantId=" + globalData[i].plantId + "]").css("border", "1px solid black");
                $("#harvestThePlant[plantId=" + globalData[i].plantId + "]").hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

`globalData` is a 2d json object. I store the details of the plants inside.

`globalNumberOfPlants` is the number of the plants.

In the *first loop* (where plantId = 1) everything's right, but in the *second loop*(or the 3rd etc.) (where plantId = 2) the css do nothing. I've checked the other variables inside the loop where the javascript is calculating the datas, and they're correct, but css doesn't show them.

My html code:

```
<div id="littlePlantStatus" plantId="1">
                    <div id="waterStatus"><div id="waterLevel" plantId="1"></div></div>
                    <div id="lifeStatus"><div id="lifeLevel" plantId="1"></div></div>
                    <div id="floweringStatus"><div id="floweringLevel" plantId="1"></div></div>
                    <div id="plantActions">
                        <input type="button" id="waterThaPlant"/><input type="button" id="addFertilizer"/><input type="button" id="checkThePlant" />
                        <input type="button" id="harvestThePlan"style="display: none;" plantId="1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div id="littlePlantStatus" plantId="2">
                    <div id="waterStatus"><div id="waterLevel" plantId="2"></div></div>
                    <div id="lifeStatus"><div id="lifeLevel" plantId="2"></div></div>
                    <div id="floweringStatus"><div id="floweringLevel" plantId="2"></div></div>
                    <div id="plantActions">
                        <input type="button" id="waterThaPlant"/><input type="button" id="addFertilizer"/><input type="button" id="checkThePlant" />
                        <input type="button" id="harvestThePlan"style="display: none;" plantId="2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So for the *second loop*, the jQuery can't find the elements. What's wrong?

Comment: element `id` attributes need to be unique, or instead of using id's use classes and use a class selector instead ie: `$(".waterLevel[plantId=1]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same id can not be used twice in same html page. If it is being used more than one time than it works with first element.

```
<div id="littlePlantStatus1" >
    <div class="waterStatus"><div class="waterLevel" ></div></div>
    <div class="lifeStatus"><div class="lifeLevel" ></div></div>
    <div class="floweringStatus"><div class="floweringLevel" ></div></div>
    <div class="plantActions">
        <input type="button" class="waterThaPlant"/><input type="button" class="addFertilizer"/><input type="button" class="checkThePlant" />
        <input type="button" class="harvestThePlan"style="display: none;" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="littlePlantStatus2" >
    <div class="waterStatus"><div class="waterLevel" ></div></div>
    <div class="lifeStatus"><div class="lifeLevel" ></div></div>
    <div class="floweringStatus"><div class="floweringLevel" ></div></div>
    <div class="plantActions">
        <input type="button" class="waterThaPlant"/><input type="button" class="addFertilizer"/><input type="button" class="checkThePlant" />
        <input type="button" class="harvestThePlan"style="display: none;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This coded should work.

```
var i,elementWaterLevel, elementLifeLevel, elementFloweringLevel,floweringTime;

    for (i = 0; i < globalNumberOfPlants; i++)
    {
        var parentDiv = $('#littlePlantStatus'+globalData[i].plantId);
        elementWaterLevel = parentDiv.find(".waterLevel");
        elementLifeLevel = parentDiv.find(".lifeLevel");
        elementFloweringLevel = parentDiv.find(".floweringLevel");

        floweringTime = Math.round((globalData[i].currentFloweringTime / globalData[i].marijuanaFloweringTime) * 200);
        elementWaterLevel.css("height", Math.round((globalData[i].currentWaterLevel) * 220));
        elementLifeLevel.css("height", Math.round((globalData[i].currentLifeLevel) * 220));
        elementFloweringLevel.css("width", floweringTime);

        if (globalData[i].currentLifeLevel == 0) {
            parentDiv.css("border", "5px solid red");
        }
        else {
            if (globalData[i].currentFloweringTime / globalData[i].plantFloweringTime == 1) {
                parentDiv.css("border", "5px solid green");
                parentDiv.find(".harvestThePlant").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#littlePlantStatus").css("border", "1px solid black");
                parentDiv.find(".harvestThePlant").hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you :) i haven't know that

Answer (score 0):

This may be a result of having duplicate IDs. Each id (id="myid") should be unique throughout the document. Aside from that I would recommend double checking the values in your `globalData` variable.

For more specific help, you will need to post a simplified version your code in a jsfiddle.

Also, you could make your life easier by applying classes to your markup in your js rather than applying the styling rules directly. Good luck!